# CSP in chrome extenstion block my use of elfsight apps

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy

I've built a chrome extension using reactjs.
To the build process I've add the variable INLINE_RUNTIME_CHUNK=false as stated in:
https://drag13.io/posts/react-inline-runtimer-chunk/index.html
I don't see any js inline code in my index.html file.

My extension uses elfsight application (try to run https://static.elfsight.com/platform/platform.js).

After loading in using develper tools to chrome I'm getting:

Refused to load the script 'https://static.elfsight.com/platform/platform.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval' 'inline-speculation-rules' http://localhost:* [http://127.0.0.1:*"](http://127.0.0.1:*%22). Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.

I'm using manifest version 3 (as chrome store won't allow version 2 anymore).
That's the part in the manifest json:
"content_security_policy": {
"extension_pages": "script-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval'; script-src-elem https://static.elfsight.com/platform/platform.js 'self'; object-src 'self'"
}

What can I do to allow this use of code?

I've built a chrome extension using reactjs.
To the build process I've add the variable INLINE_RUNTIME_CHUNK=false as stated in:
https://drag13.io/posts/react-inline-runtimer-chunk/index.html
I don't see any js inline code in my index.html file.

Comment: ManifestV3 forbids external scripts in extension pages, so you can't use it. Put the file inside your extension directory and load it as you load your other scripts.

Comment: Can you please explain more @wOxxOm?
After the build I have the index.html file which has links to the js bundle files

Comment: I've written the entire project as react components. How can I extract this the way you suggested?

Comment: Download platform.js, put it in your extension directory, and load it as `<script src=platform.js></script>`

Answer (score 0):

The script-src you've defined and the script-src in the error message don't match, which means you likely have two CSPs set. Adding another can only make it stricter. You need to identify where the CSP in the error message is set and modify that policy.